# Why doesn't reducing line-height reduce (click) area?

Tags: css, angular, onclick, grid-layout, line-height

I'm working on a personal project to have thumbnails for images that you can scroll through and click to set the main image.  I noticed an odd thing happening.

I re-created the issue in a Stackblitz project here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fidgzq?file=src/styles.css)

If I set the line-height of `.thumbnail-image-button-icon` to `20px` in thumbnails-display.component.css (or import ~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css in style.css), the area that the "Next Thumbnail Page Clicked" will fire is beyond the area of the `.thumbnail-image-button-down` button.

[image]

But, if the line-height is `inherit`, which computes to normal (without importing the angular theme), the area that the "Next Thumbnail Page Clicked" will fire is exactly around the `.thumbnail-image-button-down` button.

[image]

I thought reducing the line-height may have done so visually, but left the div expanded, but, as you can see in the screenshots, the heights are significantly different.  Also, if you inspect the `.thumbnail-image-button-down` button, you can see it isn't expanded.

How can I reduce the size of the `.thumbnail-image-button-down` button as well as the area that "Next Thumbnail Page Clicked" will fire?

Comment: Consider simplifying the problem and posting the code in the question itself.

Comment: Stackblitz requires third-party cookies to be enabled, so putting your code there doesn't let me actually look at it. Even a web page where this is deployed would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because of big `font-size: 5em` which is 80px. If you specify `line-height` less than 80px then clickable area goes beyond those boundaries anyway.

The solution might be preventing that overflow:

```
.thumbnail-image-button-icon {
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-te3mqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fthumbnails-display%2Fthumbnails-display.component.css)**

Comment: That makes sense and it fixes the issue.  Thanks!